# how to pass a file to a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to pass a file script01.txt to a function moduleA.get_text(). I got an error saying undefined name script01. Isn't the argument the name of file?

```
import moduleA as moduleA
script01=moduleA.get_text(script01)
```

Comment: If script01 is the name of the file it's a string literal and should be inside quotes.

Comment: `script01` is the name of a variable - one that doesn't exist yet, thus the error.  `"script01"` might perhaps be the name of a script, although without the source code to `get_text()` I have no idea if that's what it's looking for.

Comment: You should probably start with the python docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=file#file

Answer (score 1):

You have to put quotes:

```
moduleA.get_text('script01')
```

If you do not put quotes, then `script01` is considered a variable. Therefore you have to define it:

```
script01 = '<my filename>'
moduleA.get_text(script01)
```

Of course you can assign the result to a new variable:

`a_variable = moduleA.get_text(script01)`